# How to remove strings which don't contain any number using (regex update)?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have already a regex `(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[/][a-zA-Z\d]+)+)` which matches correctly:

> cb/09/06233/full 13/02513/MAJOR ADA/333

but also matches incorrectly

> industrial/warehouse

How can I update my regex to exclude phrases without numbers?

I've tried `(?=\d)` to add somewhere inside but no effect.

Comment: You are close. Try adding `(?=\S*\d)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x3iUKd/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead `(?=[^\d\s]*\d)` to assert what is on the right is not a whitespace char or a digit.

For that you could use a character class `[^\d\s]*` to match not a digit or a whitespace char and a quantifier to repeat that 0+ times. Then match a digit `\d`.

```
(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:/[a-zA-Z\d]+)+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RBEy8Y/2)

Comment: It's good but why it doesn't match fully `ada/333` while matches `ADA/333`? I know it's not in above set.

Comment: Found a bug. Probably you forgot about slash at `\d`: `(?=[^\d\s]*\d)`

Comment: @Peter.k You are right, I forgot to escape the `\d`. Updated accordingly.